# Install issue in windows 7 SQL Server 2008

Tags: windows-7, sql-server-2008

I keep trying to install SQL Server 2008 on windows 7 but after a while and more than half installation i get this error:

[image]

Comment: "The system can not find the file specified", for those of us who don't speak Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado/The system can not find the file specified

I would recommend reviewing the log file for information about what file the Windows Installer was trying to access.

I think this is most indicative of faulty media, you might want to re-acquire the installation packages (either by downloading again or finding another disc).

It's possible some too-eager antivirus software has gotten in between Windows Installer and the installation files as well.